# php parse error in arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html form in which I want to use the inputs in a SQL query. Instead of the first php code, I want to use the alternative php code below, but I receive php parse error for the line including `${$key} = $value` in alternative php code. maybe this syntax has been removed in newer versions of php. I appreciate if anyone could help me correct the syntax or suggest a different code to do me the same thing. Thanks in advance.

The error I receive:
Parse error: "syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}' "

html code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
<select name="my_input1">
<option value="val1">a</option>
<option value="val2">b</option>
<option value="val3">c</option>
</select>
<select name="my_input2">
<option value="val4">d</option>
<option value="val5">e</option>
</select>
</form>
```

main php code:

```
$inputs = array();
$queries = array();
foreach($inputs as $key => $value){
    array_push($queries,"table_name.column1 = $_POST['my_input1']");
    array_push($queries,"table_name.column2 = $_POST['my_input2']");
}
```

Alternative php code:

```
$inputs = array();
$queries = array();
foreach($inputs as $key => $value){
    ${$key} = $value; 
    array_push($queries,"table_name.column1 = $my_input1");
    array_push($queries,"table_name.column2 = $my_input2");
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of having this: `${$key} = $value;`, also note that you are using foreach on an empty array from what your question shows.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are receiving. Your "main" code would generate [`unexpected T_ENCAPSED AND WHITESPACE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935532/541091) -- the alternative code would be syntactically valid, but I can't tell what you are trying to accomplish other than to load local variables from `$key`.

Comment: Once you get the syntax correct, using the array in the "main" version is probably preferred - variable variables have a bad effect on readability and pollute your code with lots of unnecessary extra variables.

Comment: All that said, it looks like you are trying to construct a SQL statement with these. Having no escaping on the input, this query will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Added the exact error message.

Comment: Could you add also some motivation to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to "auto-create" `$my_input1` and `$my_input2` with `${$key}`? What for? Just use `$value` directly. You're also not going to get both at the same iteration (you would have to setup the for loop quite a bit differently, as well as the var create lines).